# How to draw an arc from points in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-canvas

I'm trying to draw an arc with drawPoints method, how can I calculate the points necessary to make an arc? (of any radius)

```
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final pointMode = ui.PointMode.points;
    final points = [
      Offset(50, 100),
      Offset(150, 75),
      Offset(250, 250),
      Offset(130, 200),
      Offset(270, 100),
    ];

    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeWidth = 1
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;
    canvas.drawPoints(pointMode, points, paint);
```

[image: arc]

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled across [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/paths-in-flutter-a-visual-guide-6c906464dcd0) which helped me a lot drawing arcs (didn't do it with points though), but maybe it helps anyway.